# How can I determine which element is found from an electron count vs binding energy graph

Tags: electrons, binding-energy, elements

I am given tables of data that I have made into graphs with electron count vs binding energy. The goal of this assignment is to determine the element of the surface material using data that was gathered in an X-ray photoelectron spectroscopy experiment. This graph is one I made from data that represents carbon.

[image: carbon]

I know that the peaks in the graph are where I should be looking to determine the element, but I am not sure what to do next.

[image: element 1]
[image: element 2]

This is extra credit for a honors physics 1 class, so this content isn't being covered in class. Any insight into XPS would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insight into XPS: there are tons of books, and good ones for an introduction are

An introduction to surface analysis by XPS and AES by Watts and Wolstenholme

Practical Surface Analysis by Briggs and Seah

or simply the Wikipedia article

The position (binding energy of the maximum) of the peak is characteristic for one transition of one element. For example the Carbon data you have is the transition of an electron from a Carbon 1s state to vacuum. You can llok up the elements in reference charts, for example at
https://srdata.nist.gov/xps/main_search_menu.aspx
(Identify spectral lines)